# Why do textures distort when polys are connected but are fine when they're not

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, edges

I've been having trouble with some polygons having distorted textures.

While I was experimenting with possible solutions to my issue I figured out that when I detach polygons via edges or vertices the once distorted textures are completely fine.

Why does that happen?

I'm working with UV coordinates.

Comment: Need pictures illustrating the problem you have and have seemed to solve so we can comment, and more specific description if possible.

Comment: Please use the [edit] to add more information to your question, in particluar describe (or post an image of) how you are mapping your textures, it makes a big difference if you are using Generated coordinates or object coordinates or  UVs. We cannot guess what you are doing from the information on your question.